# Google cloud free-tier 2nd instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I created a free tier instance in Google cloud and still running it.
Just asking if I create a 2nd free-tier instance would it be free too?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a question of number of instances, but the number of hours that your instance(s) are running per month. You can found the description [here](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier/#compute)

> Your Free Tier f1-micro instance limit is by time, not by instance. Each month, eligible use of all of your f1-micro instances is free until you have used a number of hours equal to the total hours in the current month. Usage calculations are combined across the supported regions.

Comment: First thanx for responding. Yes I know it's limited by time 744h per month. what i'm asking is if I run another free-tier instance would it take from the first instance 744h or would it have another 744h of its own? Because They say 1 non-preemptible f1-micro instance.

Comment: I asked Google directly and the documentation will be updated: all the free tier are per billing account. If you want 2 VM free, you can create 2 billing account. But, do it at your own risk, if Google detect that you try to fraud, it's possible that your account be closed.